# Can I use Badboy software in Linux?

Tags: apt

I want to Record script in Jmeter using Badboy software, but I am not able to find the build for linux.

Comment: http://www.badboy.com.au/download/send?svId=120  (from page http://www.badboy.com.au/download/add) -- though I didn't expand it to examine..

Comment: @guiverc sounds like an answer. BTW: there is a little bit of code in the download. The large parts looks like a binary that is extracted from the script.

Comment: Yeah I grabbed & looked at script too, didn't like the hidden nature of how it worked, so went no further..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing nothing about *badbay*, I opened a search engine and found http://www.badboy.com.au/download/add

…which lists http://www.badboy.com.au/download/send?svId=120 as the download for my '*linux*' machine. It downloaded a short bash script `wtm_installer_1.1.1.sh` which contained a large binary blob (a tarball) and I didn't go any further.

To run the shell screen, you just use its name:

```
./wtm_installer_1.1.1.sh
```